# Use Prometheus built-in <aggregation>_over_time() functions for range queries in API endpoints

Tags: api, prometheus

so the task is to measure certain metrics for given time period between start and end timestamps with some defined step, and then get min/max/avg value from this list of provided values.

Data is requested by HTTP API, example endpoint URL looks like this:

```
http://<prometheus_ip>:<port>/api/datasources/proxy/2/api/v1/query_range?query=container_memory_working_set_bytes{container=<container>}&start=<timestamp1>&end=<timestamp2>&step=<step>
```

Then provided list of `[timestamp,value]` is parsed by some custom methods to get min/max/avg values, which is not good, so i'd like to use Prometheus built-in `<aggregation>_over_time()` functions here, since they provide exactly what I need directly.

Found examples how it is used in Prometheus UI for querying min/max/avg from range, but is it somehow possible to use it in API requests with an above example endpoint to get min/max/avg value directly in JSON response?

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this question today, while trying to figure out the same thing.

You can indeed use the HTTP API with the functions defined in the Prometheus documentation, e.g. `avg_over_time()`:

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://<your_host>:<your_port>/api/v1/query?query=avg_over_time%28node_load5%7Binstance%3D%22localhost%3A9100%22%2Cjob%3D%22Node+Exporter%22%7D%5B12h%5D%29&time=1660577741'
```

With for instance the node_exporter for prometheus which has a field `node_load`, from which I request the average of the hour before the unix timestamp passed along. Do note that the characters in the string are just URL encoding and actually the query says:

```
query=avg_over_time(node_load5{instance="localhost:9100",job="Node Exporter"}[12h])&time=1660577741
```

I was able to found out while using the Prometheus Graph UI at `http://<your_host>:<your_port>/graph` and executing queries. If you then open the network tab of Chrome, you can see the calls being made to the HTTP API.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q1qK.png)

Perhaps good to create PR with prometheus to reflect this in the [HTTP API](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#http-api) documentation.